# Using Lucene / Mahout to find defining terms in predefined document groups

Tags: lucene, machine-learning, classification, mahout, tf-idf

I have a set of documents which have been divided into Good and Bad categories. I want to be able to predict which category new documents will fall under. One thing I am looking at is finding terms that best define each category and looking for those terms in new documents.

Awhile back I was messing around with Mahout clustering using Lucene term vectors when I learned about TF-IDF. It seems to me that what I am looking for is something similar where I would find the TermFrequency from one category, but then apply the InverseDocumentFrequency of those terms in the other category.

Does anyone know the best approach to take to find the terms that would uniquely define documents in one of these groups but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use Mahout's [Bayesian classifier](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/bayesian.html). You will label your documents as "good" or "bad" and then Mahout will be able to predict the label of an untrained document. Wikipedia [has more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_classifier) on Bayes classifiers.

Lucene data can be used as an input to mahout, see e.g. [this blog post series](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/03/16/integrating-apache-mahout-with-apache-lucene-and-solr-part-i-of-3/).

Answer (score 0):

In situations similar to this, working with ratios of differently conditioned probabilities is often done.

So in your case that would be:

P(w|good) / P(w)

and then rank by that.

The estimates would be just the maximum likelihood ones from counts:

P(w|good) = n(w,good) / n(good)

P(w) = n(w) / N = n(w) / (n(good) + n(bad))

N is the overall corpus token count, n(*) is token counts with restrictions.